# Geotiffs not displaying colour correctly in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to open geotiffs I made in ArcGIS 10.2 in MapInfo 12.5. They open in MapInfo in the right location but displayed on a blue colour scale. These should be colourful RGB images.

Trying to use the Discover enhance image tool just crashes MapInfo.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

So GeoTIFFs aren't just GeoTIFF's...

Exactly what kind of GeoTIFF have you created?

- 8bit, 16bit, 24Bit, 32bit?
- Raster, Grid?
- ...

Sofar MapInfo Pro only supports GeoTIFF Raster up to 24bit, as I recall.

Comment: They are 16bit raster, just georeferenced images.

Comment: Are they RGB or CMYK colourbased? MapInfo Pro only supports RGB

Comment: They are RGB rasters

Comment: Is it possible for you to share one of the GeoTIFF files?

Comment: Sure. Here's an example https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7fg2r9qxhor8v4/SK_permits.zip?dl=0

Comment: Looks a bit weird to me, MapInfo and IrfanView :-) In MapInfo Pro it looks blue as you said, in IrfavView it's all black and so it is in Windows Photo Viewer. IrfanView says "Original Colours 48bits per pixel, Current Colours 24bits per pixel". Are you sure it's saved as a low "bit per pixel" image?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the new 64-bit environment. It is just a matter of changing the color style in the raster tab from pseudo to RGB. Trust that they have a similar setting in the 32-bit environment.